# Gigabyte GC-TPM 2.0 Module in z87x mobo

Tags: motherboard, tpm

I purchased a Gigabyte GC-TPM2.0 Module and installed it in my ga-z87x-d3h motherboard, enabled "security device support" (pressed F10 and rebooted) however once back in the Trusted Computing section there is are no additional TPM settings to enable, it says "support disabled", Windows 10 Pro does not recognize any TPM module either.

Can't find much useful information about this on the internet either. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you end up solving the problem?